# EMR Hive Regex QueryString values

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop

I'm not great with Regex. I'm trying to capture custom log lines into a Hive table.

So far I'm able to capture the basic entries with the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elb_logs_v2_9 (

    ResponseCode STRING,
    Timestamp STRING,
    ResponseTime DOUBLE,
    RemoteIP STRING,
    URL STRING,
    UserAgent STRING,
    Referer STRING,
    Domain STRING,
    Version INT

)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
          "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (.*) \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\" (.*)$"
) LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/logfiles/';
```

Here's an example log file:

```
204 1434401743 365 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX "/tra.ck?p=1234&a=5432&evt=view&r=1434401750625285" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36" "https://referer.org/page.html" "metric.mydomain.org" 7
204 1434401743 269 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX "/tra.ck?p=1234&a=5432&evt=renderTime&v[]=10&r=1434401750650240" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36" "https://referer.org/page.html" "metric.mydomain.org" 7
```

Basic structure is:

```
ResponseCode Timestamp ResponseTimeMS RemoteIP QueryString UserAgent Referer Domain Version
```

How do I take the RegEx a step further and create columns from values in the URI? Like say a column for the `p` and `a` values, and an `eventType` to store `view` and `renderTime`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you can assume that the request is always in the same format has the parameters in correct order.

```
^([0-9]\d*) ([0-9]\d*) ([0-9]\d*) ([0-9\.X]+) "((?:.*?)p=(\d+)&a=(\d+)&evt=([^&]+).*?)" "([^"]+)" "([^"]+)" "([^"]+)" ([0-9]\d*)$
```

You can edit and play with it more here: https://regex101.com/r/gS3nO1/2

(edit) I'm assuming here that the 4th item is an IP so you can remove the X from the actual regex.